# php json_encode returning null

Tags: php, null, json

```
Array
(
    [sEcho] => 1
    [iTotalRecords] => 7521
    [iTotalDisplayRecords] => 1
    [aaData] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Nordic Capital Buys SiC Processing
                    [1] => 2010-06-21/nordic-capital-buys-sic-processing
                    [2] => PEHub Media
                    [3] => Business
                    [4] => completed
                    [5] => Nordic Capital has acquired a 70% stake in SiC Processing AG, a German industrial recycling company, from Frog Capital. No sale price was disclosed.  SiC Processing’s founding family retains a 25% holding, while former lead investor Zouk Ventures retains a 5% stake.

                    [6] => Admin, China, Frog Capital, Germany, Italy, Iyad Omari, Manufacturing, Norway, PEHub Media, Photovoltaic Wafer Manufacturing, Renewable Energy, Semiconductor, United States
                )

        )

)

echo json_encode($myArr);
```

> {"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":7521,"iTotalDisplayRecords":"1","aaData":[["
>   Nordic Capital Buys SiC Processing</a></div>","
>   2010-06-21/nordic-capital-buys-sic-processing</div>","PEHub Media","Business","completed",***null***,"
>   Admin, China, Frog Capital, Germany, Italy, Iyad Omari, Manufacturing, Norway, PEHub Media, Photovoltaic Wafer Manufacturing, Renewable Energy, Semiconductor, United States]]}

**Note the null in the middle of the string after completed**

Why is this, what escape/manipulation do I need to perform in order to encode this?

I have tried, `addslashes`

Comment: Works for me. Check your PHP configuration, I think json_* stuff can be disabled.

Comment: Please provide the PHP code used to construct the example array (and please check your questions carefully when posting - examples provided should do what you intend them to!)

Comment: Can we get a `var_export` of the source array please?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the manual:

> Note that if you try to encode an
>   array containing non-utf values,
>   you'll get null values in the
>   resulting JSON string.  You can
>   batch-encode all the elements of an
>   array with the array_map function:

```
$encodedArray = array_map(utf8_encode, $myArr);
echo json_encode($encodedArray);
```

Comment: Thanks seengee, perfect. I actually used array_map(htmlentities... for my situation, but this saved the day.

Comment: It should be noted that suggesting utf8_encode() is not usually a great idea, as it blindly assumes the input is ISO-8859-1. If you're facing the problem, it's important that you first figure out what your character set *IS*, and only THEN convert (http://php.net/iconv can help with the second part if you're NOT dealing with ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 1):

Actually it doesn't return null, http://codepad.org/A34KdUf5.

Maybe your PHP version doesn't support json_encode().

Comment: Please check my question again i have updated with full code, as json_encode is working with rest of array.

Comment: In copying and pasting, you probably inadvertently put it in UTF-8 form, while the original string likely wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on 5.2.13. Ensure you're using at least PHP 5.2.0 and that PHP wasn't compiled with --disable-json. You may also want to check that error reporting (and/or logging) is enabled.

Comment: Please check my question again i have updated with full code, as json_encode is working with rest of array.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is `$store_name = utf8_encode(name_of_varaible)` but please make sure that your character set is `ISO-8859-1.`