# when does json_encode return null

Tags: php, json

I have an api where I return json. json_encode on arrays are returning null. In what cases does json_encode return null? Also what other values does json_encode return to indicate a failure

Comment: You should search before ask http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: The `json_encode()` returns a `JSON` encoded string on success or FALSE on failure. It won't return NULL.

Comment: it returns null for me. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @PrinceGato what do you get when you echo gettype(json_encode($json));?

Comment: @PrinceGato, can you post your array in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

> Returns a JSON encoded string on success or FALSE on failure.

**[DOCUMENTATION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**

`json_encode()` does not return `null`.

If some values in the json string are null, please check this: [php json_encode returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180690/php-json-encode-returning-null)

Comment: It returns null for me. I am trying to figure out why.