# php json_encode retuns false

Tags: php, json

I've got this object. This is the var_dump of my object:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
  ["status"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["sql"]=>
  string(122) "SELECT * FROM `story`"
  ["story"]=>
  array(12) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["gb_id"]=>
    string(12) "tYQz0zq5-DQC"
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["title"]=>
    string(14) "1893.21.04-148"
    ["story"]=>
    string(4026) "<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P>HTML STUFF</P></TEXTFORMAT>"
    ["image"]=>
    NULL
    ["views"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["username"]=>
    string(9) "username"
    ["password"]=>
    string(6) "789456"
    ["email"]=>
    string(7) "email"
    ["story_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

But when I try to json_encode it, it returns nothing. Does anyone have an idea why?

Has it anything to do with the fact that it could be to big? (Because a left out some big chunks of data above )

Comment: stdClass is probably not encodable. Where is this coming from? If it's the return value of a json_decode, pass `true` as the second parameter to get an array instead of an object.

Comment: `json_encode` cannot return `NULL`, it can only return a `string` or boolean `FALSE`.  If it returns `FALSE` there was an error.

Comment: After you call to `json_encode`, make a call to `json_last_error` and check its return value here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: It *returns* nothing? Or you just haven't prefaced it with an `echo` statement, and therefore aren't getting any output?

Comment: You got some non-utf values on the part that you didn't posted ? It can be the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180690/php-json-encode-returning-null, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null

Comment: Can you provide a `var_export`?

Comment: An stdClass is encodebale. The problem is utf-8 formatting. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Maerlyn There's nothing wrong with `json_encode`ing the `stdClass`.  Quick example: http://3v4l.org/hqnLe