# JSON give me null in one of my data when should be there is data on there

Tags: php, json, null, output

This is my php code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pro_artukel";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Errorquery:  '.$query);
$rows = array();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$data = "{pro_artikul:".json_encode($rows)."}";
echo $data;
```

Here the result:

```
{
  "pro_artikul": [
    {
      "kode_provinsi": "PR001",
      "artikel": "Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta adalah Daerah Istimewa setingkat provinsi di Indonesia yang merupakan peleburan Negara Kesultanan Yogyakarta dan Negara Kadipaten Paku Alaman. Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta yang terletak di bagian selatan Pulau Jawa bagian tengah dan berbatasan dengan Provinsi Jawa Tengah dan Samudera Hindia. Daerah Istimewa yang memiliki luas 3.185,80 km2 ini terdiri atas satu kota dan empat kabupaten, yang terbagi lagi menjadi 78 kecamatan dan 438 desa\/kelurahan. Daerah Istimewa ini sering diidentikkan dengan Kota Yogyakarta sehingga secara kurang tepat disebut dengan Jogja, Yogya, Yogyakarta, Jogjakarta. Walaupun memiliki luas terkecil ke dua setelah Provinsi DKI Jakarta, Daerah Istimewa ini terkenal di tingkat nasional dan internasional. Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta menjadi tempat tujuan wisata andalan setelah Provinsi Bali.\r\n\r\nsumber : http:\/\/id.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Daerah_Istimewa_Yogyakarta"
    },
    {
      "kode_provinsi": "PR002",
      "artikel": "Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta (DKI Jakarta, Jakarta Raya) adalah ibu kota negara Indonesia. Jakarta merupakan satu-satunya kota di Indonesia yang memiliki status setingkat provinsi. Jakarta terletak di bagian barat laut Pulau Jawa. Dahulu pernah dikenal dengan nama Sunda Kelapa (sebelum 1527), Jayakarta (1527-1619), \r\n\r\nsumber : http:\/\/id.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Daerah_Khusus_Ibukota_Jakarta"
    },
    {
      "kode_provinsi": "PR003",
      "artikel": "Jawa Barat adalah sebuah provinsi di Indonesia. Ibukotanya berada di Kota Bandung. Perkembangan Sejarah menunjukkan bahwa Provinsi Jawa Barat merupakan Provinsi yang pertama dibentuk di wilayah Indonesia. Provinsi Jawa Barat dibentuk berdasarkan UU No.11 Tahun 1950, tentang Pembentukan Provinsi Jawa Barat. Jawa Barat merupakan provinsi dengan jumlah penduduk terbanyak di Indonesia. Bagian barat laut provinsi Jawa Barat berbatasan langsung dengan Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta, ibukota negara Indonesia. Pada tahun 2000, Provinsi Jawa Barat dimekarkan dengan berdirinya Provinsi Banten, yang berada di bagian barat. Saat ini terdapat wacana untuk mengubah nama Provinsi Jawa Barat menjadi Provinsi Pasundan, dengan memperhatikan aspek historis wilayah ini. Namun hal ini mendapatkan penentangan dari wilayah Jawa Barat lainnya seperti Cirebon dimana tokoh masyarakat asal Cirebon menyatakan bahwa jika nama Jawa Barat diganti dengan nama Pasundan seperti yang berusaha digulirkan oleh Bapak Soeri\r\n\r\nsumber : http:\/\/id.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Jawa_Barat"
    },
    {
      "kode_provinsi": "PR004",
      "artikel": null
    },
    {
      "kode_provinsi": "PR005",
      "artikel": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I think mybe in json there is some limit length or something
can someone explain what happen. please i'm really headache'

Comment: please there is any one know what happen

Comment: `pro_artikul` should be quoted for proper JSON: `"{\"pro_artikul\":".json_encode($rows)."}";`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

Comment: Can you `var_dump($rows)` and add the result as an edit to your question?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180690/php-json-encode-returning-null it might be a problem with non-utf characters

Comment: thank to u all. my problem has resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change this** because this one is generating a malformed json

```
$data = "{pro_artikul:".json_encode($rows)."}";
echo $data;
```

**to this**

```
$data = json_encode(array('pro_artikul' => $rows));
echo $data;
```

**Update 1 :**

It looks like your data contain some non utf-8 char. Before select condition in your sql statement put this

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

This one might help

Comment: are you sure all "artikel" fields contain some data. If yes then can you show me that data