# malformed JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am a .NET guy with fairly long experience but recently pulled into a PHP project so need some help. I have this PHP code which prepares a final song object and then JSONifies it with `json_encode()` but I strangly I am seeing some extra value `null` added at the end of JSON string and I dont seem to understand why is that.

Here is my PHP code

```
foreach($result as $item) {
    ++$index;
    $hymn->id=$item['id'];
    $hymn->refrain=$item['refrain'];

    if ($index == 1) { $hymn->stanza1=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 2) { $hymn->stanza2=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 3) { $hymn->stanza3=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 4) { $hymn->stanza4=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 5) { $hymn->stanza5=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 6) { $hymn->stanza6=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 7) { $hymn->stanza7=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 8) { $hymn->stanza8=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 9) { $hymn->stanza9=$item['stanzaText']; }
    if ($index == 10) { $hymn->stanza10=$item['stanzaText']; }
}

json_encode($hymn);
```

Above code produces a JSON with extra `null` after the ending curly braces as shown below.

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "refrain" : "Jesus, Jesus, how I trust Him!\nHow I\u2019ve proved   Him o\u2019er and o\u2019er;\nJesus, Jesus, precious Jesus!\nOh, for grace to trust Him more!",
    "stanza1" : "Tis so sweet to trust in Jesus,\nJust to take Him at His Word;\nJust to rest upon His promise,\nAnd to know, \u201cThus saith the Lord!\u201d",
    "stanza2" : "Oh, how sweet to trust in Jesus,\nJust to trust His cleansing blood;\nAnd in simple faith to plunge me\n\u2019Neath the healing, cleansing flood!",
    "stanza3" : "Yes, \u2019tis sweet to trust in Jesus,\nJust from sin and self to cease;\nJust from Jesus simply taking\nLife and rest, and joy and peace.",
    "stanza4" : "I\u2019m so glad I learned to trust Thee,\nPrecious Jesus, Savior, Friend;\nAnd I know that Thou art with me,\nWilt be with me to the end"
 }null
```

Kindly help me to understand what wrong am I doing here?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180690/php-json-encode-returning-null

Comment: `@codenut` I believe my problem is different then the one in the thread you mentioned. I have all JSON elements exactly as expected within the curly braces. But after the ending curly braces it just adds extra `null`. and just dont understand from where that comes.

Comment: can you post the input here?

Comment: `@codenut` In my original DB result-set itself there is extra null and I need to figure out that first. Thanks for your interest to help anyways...

Comment: can you to show `var_dump(json_encode($hymn));`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All friends, I apologize as I should have made this an answer before but problem is not with JSON. It is with fetchAll(). Thanks for analyzing and helping me.

Answer (score 1):

wrong. json_encode does NOT create that null at the end, something else, after this code, does. show us the rest of the code, and we might be able to spot what's making it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this answer. You could enclose your output from echo-ing the json result in quotes to confirm this., i.e. `echo '"' . json_encode($hymn) . '"';`

Comment: I believe `null` is `json_encode($hymn)` from second loop iteration :)

Comment: @vp_arth perhaps. but in the code shown, json_encode is only run once, after the forEach loop finishes