# Weird behavior of fetchAll() - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am struggling with weird behavior of fetchAll(). I am executing a stored proc using PDO which returns the set of songs.

Here is my PHP code

```
    $sql = "call getHymn(?)";
    $param = array($id);
    $result = $this->db->getData($sql,$param);
```

here is the `getData` function

```
public function getData($sql,$param=[])
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($param);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
        /*return($stmt->fetchAll());*/
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I execute stored proc in MySQL it returns me 3 rows as expected. But when I execute it through PDO and use fetchall() then I get extra `null` outside the array..could not find any help anywhere, not even in PHP documentation. My fetchAll() output looks like below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [refrain] => 
        [stanzaId] => 1
        [stanzaText] => Amazing grace! How sweet the sound 
that saved a wretch like me! 
I once was lost, but now am found; 
was blind, but now I see.
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [refrain] => 
        [stanzaId] => 2
        [stanzaText] => 'Twas grace that taught my heart to fear, 
and grace my fears relieved; 
how precious did that grace appear 
the hour I first believed.
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [refrain] => 
        [stanzaId] => 3
        [stanzaText] => Through many dangers, toils, and snares, 
I have already come; 
'tis grace hath brought me safe thus far, 
and grace will lead me home
    )
)
null
```

And here is my stored proc which is quite simple and straight forward

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getHymn`(IN `hid` INT)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    select 
        a.id, a.refrain, b.stanzaId, b.stanzaText 
    from 
        hymns a, hymnstanza b 
    where a.id = hid and a.id = b.hymnid;
END
```

Can anybody help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Does your table rows contains quotes?

Comment: Since that `null` is not part of the result set, it's unlikely that it's output by PDO at all and simply originates from some completely unrelated part of your code.

Comment: Also, why `catch` the `PDOException` to then just rethrow it as a plain `Exception`?! Simply don't `try..catch`!

Comment: Also, is it possible you're fighting the same unrelated problem as before...!? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33949972/476

Comment: `@Yuri` - yes it does contain single quotes as well as double quotes.

Comment: `@deceze` - With all due respect, I dont think you are reading code properly. I have pasted the output of `print_r($stmt->fetchAll()`. There is no code of mine whatsoever which causes this issue. 

Also dont bother about code cleanup. I will do it later. IF you can help nailing the issue I have stated it would be appreciated.

Comment: `@deceze` - the thread you referred was by me and it posted by mistake as I had not doen enough homework before posting that. I have already answered and clarified the same in that thread recently.

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to be misreading here. Your output says `Array ( .. ) null`. `print_r` will most certainly not output an array *followed by `null`*. Those are two separate values being output at two different places in your code. Also, if you put @ mentions in ` backticks, we won't get notified.

Comment: Is the `return` statement actually commented?

Comment: @decez I am not sure how to best represent this. But here is the crux of the matter. When I print the result set which I receive from 'fetchAll()'. I am getting extra value `null` printed after the array is printed. I have no extra code in there. I am just printing whatever is returned by `fetchAll()`.

Comment: @hjpotter92, yes it is commented because I am echoing the output of `fetchAll()` as web response as part of my debugging the code.

Comment: @decez - also you see I have absolutely nothing echoed or print_r'ed after `fetchAll()`. So I am also not sure from where that `null` is printed. However I did come across a thread on internet which says that there is known bug in `fetchAll()`. Here is the thread which says that-**https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/issues/70**. So I believe I am victim of that bug. However all I am interested is to know if there is any workaround if there is a big.

Comment: Are you using [the CSV reader class](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/blob/master/src/Reader.php) that [that fetchAll bug](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/issues/70) refers to? It doesn't look like you are from your source code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, friends. I found the bug now and @decez you were absolutely correct that there was some extra echo statement which was causing `null` to appear after the array is printed. Feeling quite relaxed as after almost 12 hours I was able to move on successfully. THANK YOU ALL especially @decez.

Just to elaborate what mistake I had done, I was double JSONifying the output of fetchAll().